# SQL fields with blank space at end of fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field in Oracle that has a blank character at the end so instead of it reading "12345" it reads "12345 "

The length of this field differs on different records but may also have a blank at the end. How may I write in SQL to identify those records that have a blank at the end?

Comment: assuming they are varchars, you can compare their string length with the length of them with spaces trimmed.

Comment: I was trying something like this select * from (table) where rtrim(column) = '% %'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
Select ColumnName from tablename where columnname like '% '
```

Comment: Yes, just my thinking.

Comment: You star that is perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

this untested query should do what you want:

```
select * from tabler where length(col)>length(rtrim(col));
```

This query compares the length of the string including trailing blanks with the length after trailing blanks have been removed by the RTRIM function, and only returns rows where these two lengths differ.

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: I added comment because post was flagged as low quality due to length.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use REGEXP_ functions in cases like these (and for many other cases as well - helpful to know regular expressions):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(my_column, '[:space:]$')
```

Please note that this will find trailing tabs, carriage returns, etc. as well as spaces.